# Random Forest Notation Confusion

Tags: machine-learning, self-study, random-forest, random-variable

I've been trying to mathematically understand the random forest algorithm but I've been confused with the notation. In these [slides](http://math.bu.edu/people/mkon/MA751/L19RandomForestMath.pdf) (page 17), it is stated:

> Let $\mathbf{x} = (x_1, ..., x_d)$ be a microarray of a glioma cancer sample in its initial stages. Then each feature $x_i$ is a random variable with some distribution.
>   For fixed $i$, let $X_i$ be a model random variable whose probability distribution is the same as the $x_i$ numbers in the microarray.
>   Then the model random vector $\mathbf{X} = (X_1, ..., X_d)$ has a joint distribution which is the same as our microarray
>   samples $\mathbf{x} = (x_1, ..., x_d)$.

Traditionally lower case $x$'s are referred to in probability and statistics as realizations (or observations) and bigger case $X$'s are referred to as random variables. My question regarding this paragraph is what is meant here by **model random vector** and why is $\mathbf{x}$ referred to as a random vector rather than the sample observations?

In page 19, it is stated that:

> Assume training set of microarrays:
>   $$D = \{(\mathbf{x}_1, y_1), ..., (\mathbf{x}_n, y_n)\}$$
>   drawn randomly from a (possibly unknown) probability
>   distribution $(\mathbf{x}_i, y_i) \sim (\mathbf{X}, Y)$.

Here the training set is given by $D = \{(\mathbf{x}_1, y_1), ..., (\mathbf{x}_1, y_1)\}$ and in another [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1511.05741.pdf) (page 4) the training sample is given by $\mathcal{D}_n = ((\mathbf{X}_1 , Y_1 ), ... , (\mathbf{X}_n , Y_n))$, what is the difference between the two? is $D$ an observed sample while $\mathcal{D}_n$ is an unobserved sample? And finally is $\mathbf{x}$ and $D$ the same (an $n \times m$ matrix)? 
Sorry for the primitive questions and thanks is advance.

Comment: The quotes you gave do not seem to contradict to what you’ve said, they use uppercase for random variables and lowercase for realizations, observed samples, aren’t they?

Comment: Hi @Tim, This part has confused me the most "Then each feature $x_i$ **is a random variable with some distribution**." Why did he refer to the lower case $x_i$ as random variables (which therefore makes $\mathbf{x}$ a random vector)?

Comment: Those are only the slides, hard to comment on slides without the comment that was given on them. My *guess* would be that they mean that x is a realization of a random variable.

Comment: Thank you @Tim.